# How can inflate a layout containing listview in a alert dialog?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, custom-adapter

I am using a listview with a custom adapter in a layout.
Now i am trying to bring that layout containing list to my alertdialog.
I tried to bring simple layouts not containing list to alert dialog with this code and its is working good.
But i am unable to bring the list containing layout into alertdialog.

```
           AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
           dialog.setView( getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.smill, null ) );
           dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.androidsmile);
           dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);


           dialog.setTitle( "Select smiley");
           dialog.setPositiveButton( "Cancel", null );
           dialog.show();
```

Comment: can you elaborate what wrong happening with your application?
does it force close or listview is not shown or anything else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All you are doing is inflating a view into your alert dialog. You aren't setting the adapter on that listview so of course it's going to appear to not be working (since its empty).

You need to do something like:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.smill, null);
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
YourCustomAdapter adapter = new YourCustomAdapter(parameters...);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
dialog.setView(view);
...
...
...
dialog.show();
```

Comment: avoid passing null as the root view for the layoutInflater. If this is done inside your adapter you can pass rootview or convertview or whatever view is hosting this alert dialog